# What does SCTE35 tags/marker do? How hls parse the SCTE35-CMD?

Tags: macos, safari, http-live-streaming, m3u8, scte-35

My question is what's the difference in `SCTE35-IN` , `SCTE35-OUT`, and in `SCTE35-CMD` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is well documented in the HLS specification: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-11#section-4.4.5.1.1.

The contents of SCTE35-CMD are as described in the SCTE35 specification, currently available to download with no cost at https://www.scte.org/standards/library/catalog/scte-35-digital-program-insertion-cueing-message/.

Answer (score 0):

HLS EXT-X-DATERANGE tags that carry SCTE-35 use these attributes.

For SCTE-35 `Splice Insert` Commands and `Time Signal` commands that are used to signal an ad splice:

The `SCTE35-OUT` attribute is used to indicate the START of an ad break,

The `SCTE35-IN` attribute is used to indicate the END of an ad break,

For SCTE-35 Commands that don't signal an ad break ( `Splice Null`, `Bandwidth Reservation`, `Splice Schedule`, and some `Time Signals`), the `SCTE-35-CMD` attribute is used.

the value for `SCTE35-OUT`, `SCTE35-IN`, and `SCTE35-CMD` is the SCTE-35 Cue messsage in hex instead of the usual base64.